# Is a Contraction also a Contraction under equivalent metrics?

Tags: lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

> **Definition of a Contraction**. Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Then a map $T : X → X$ is called a contraction on $X$ if there exists $q ∈ [0, 1)$ such that $d(T(x),T(y)) \le q d(x,y)$ for all $x, y$ in $X$.

My question: Does a contraction remain a contraction under an equivalent metric $d'$?

I know that [Lipschitz continuity is not preserved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822493/lipschitz-constant-of-a-function-preserved-under-equivalent-metrics) in general under equivalent metrics, and since the two definitions are quite similar we may believe contractions are not preserved.

However, contractions have the additional requirement that they map a metric space to itself, so changing the scale of the metric will not create issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is still negative. For example, the map $Tx=x/2$ is a contraction on $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. However, it is not a contraction under the spherical metric 
$$d(x, y) = |\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y|$$
(Note that for strictly monotone continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ the formula $d(x, y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ defines an equivalent metric.) Indeed, $d(2, 1)>d(4, 2)$ because 
$$
\tan^{-1}2 - \tan^{-1} 1 > \tan^{-1}4 - \tan^{-1} 2
$$
as verified by [a numerical computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(arctan(2)-arctan(1))%20-%20(arctan(4)-arctan(2))).

Answer (score 0):

user357151 showed this isn't true for equivalent metrics in general.

However, if we restrict ourselves to metrics induced by equivalent norms, we get an interesting relation.

> Consider $T:V \to V$, where $V$ is a normed vector space with two equivalent norms, say $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$. Then, there exists some positive constants $a,b$ such that:
>
> $$ a ||x||_1 \le ||x||_2 \le b ||x||_1 \text{ for all }x\in V $$
>
> Additionally, assume that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are induced by the first and second norm respectively, and that we have
>
> $$ d_1( T(x), T(y)) \le c d_1(x, y) $$

We have the relation

$$ \begin{align*}
 d_2(T(x),T(y) ) &\le b\times c \times d_1(x,y) \\
&\le \frac{b}{a} \times c \times  d_2(x,y)\\
&= c_*  d_2(x,y)  \end{align*} $$

with $c_* = \frac{b}{a} \times c$.

My result was obtained [with the help of this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056283/equivalent-norms-on-mathbbrd-and-a-contraction).

Hence we may suspect we can lose the contraction properties if the ratio $b/a$ is large enough. This is indeed the case.

> Consider the following function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$,
>
> $$f(x) = (.9\max(|x_1|,|x_2|), .9 \max(|x_1|,|x_2|))$$
>
> Then $f$ is a contraction under the metric induced by the maximum norm $d_\infty$, but not under the metric induced by the Manhattan norm $d_1$.

Indeed,

$$ \begin{align*} d_\infty( f(x), f(y) ) &= \max( |f_1(x) - f_1(y)|, |f_2(x) - f_2(y)| ) \\ 
&= .9|\max(|x_1|,|x_2|) - \max(|y_1|,|y_2|)|
 \\
&\le  .9\max(|x_1 - y_1|,|x_2 - y_2|)  \\
&= .9 d_\infty(x, y)\end{align*}
 $$
where the inequality is obtained [from this relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041125/why-is-absolute-difference-of-max-of-functions-less-than-max-of-absolute-differe). Note that $c = .9$.

However, $f$ is not a contraction for a metric induced by the Manhattan norm $d_1$. For example, taking $x = (1,0)$, $y = (0,0)$, we have

$$\begin{align*} d_1(x,y) &= 1 + 0 = 1 \\
d_1(f(x),f(y)) &= .9 + .9 = 1.8  \end{align*}$$

which proves that $f$ is not a contraction.

Note that for vectors of length 2, the maximum and Manhattan norms follow the following relation,

$$ ||x||_\infty \le ||x||_1 \le 2 ||x||_\infty  $$

$b = 2$ and $a = 1$, and so $c_* = 1.8$.

Similarly,

> Consider the following function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$,
>
> $$g(x) = (.7(|x_1|+|x_2|), 0)$$
>
> Then $g$ is a contraction under the metric induced by the Manhattan norm $d_1$, but not under the metric induced by the maximum norm $d_\infty$

We have

$$ \begin{align*} d_1(g(x),g(y)) &= .7(||x_1| - |y_1|| + ||x_2| - |y_2||) \\
&\le .7(|x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|) \\
&= .7 d_1(x,y)
\end{align*}
$$

but we get, with $x = (1,1)$ and $y=(0,0)$,

$$d_\infty(g(x),g(y)) = 2 \times .7 = 1.4 d_\infty(x,y)$$

Again, that's because

$$  .5||x||_1 \le  ||x||_\infty \le ||x||_1  $$